# How to search Kiva Loans for "not equal to"?

Tags: url, sphinx

The Kiva site creates custom searches by URL. The examples below return a few results that differ enough to be meaningful.  I am just looking for the "not equal to" code.  The actual counts will vary over time as available loans change.

Loan partner = #148 (value at writing = 28)

http://www.kiva.org/lend?partner_id=148

Loan partner = #148 AND gender = female (value at writing = 18)

http://www.kiva.org/lend?partner_id=148&gender=female

I have tried some common ways of getting "not equal to", but they are not working.

All = 28

http://www.kiva.org/lend?partner_id=148&gender!=male

http://www.kiva.org/lend?partner_id=148&gender<>male

http://www.kiva.org/lend?partner_id=148&gender-male

I am not sure what value to use for a negative.  I want to create a search that excludes a handful of loan partners, out of hundreds.  I could of course do an inclusion for the the others, but exclusion would be a much smaller, easier to maintain query.

Update: Kiva is using sphinx search (http://sphinxsearch.com/) for loan searchs

Update 2: I have looked around am not finding anything on the Spinix site.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equals_sign#Not_equal) has a list of the values used by most programming languages (~=, !=, /=, =/=, or <>) and none of them seem to be working.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about using a website and not a programming question.

Comment: @Dukeling it is coding a query for a backend data source that is unknown.  I looked around to see if I could figure out what language it uses but have not discovered that.

Comment: have you tried `gender=!male`, or `gender=-male`?

Comment: @AlanHoover I just did, neither worked

Comment: Have you tried `gender!male`?

Comment: @g3mini that does not work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just checked their website, and it is impossible.
`$_GET["somevar"]` will apparently search for something with its value. If you set `$_GET['gender']` to `!=male` You're basically saying "The string you are searching for is not male". But, if it's not male, then what is it? So it kind of just does nothing... You have to tell it what it is. So you could put `gender=female` to find anything not male.

Comment: Thank you, I have used an inclusion search in my link.  Posted the link to the [team web site.](http://www.kiva.org/team/fsm/messages?msgID=433080#msg_433080)